# How to relate more than one join CDbCriteria Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x

I have a problem to relate tables in JOIN with `CDbCriteria`. I got it to work with a single JOIN between two tables that are related but I have the following case:

structure of tables with fields to relate:

```
table Tbl_recibo       table tbl_domicilio       table tbl_entidad
  Idrecibo               Iddomicilio          Identidad
  nombre                 nombre               nombre
  Iddomicilio            Identidad
```

Codigo SQL:

```
SELECT
  `rec`.`idrecibo` AS 'Num_Recibo',
  `dom`.`matricula`,
  `dom`.`federado`,
  `ent`.`nombre` AS 'profesional',
  `dom`.`calle` AS 'domicilio'
FROM
  `tbl_recibo` AS rec
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_domicilio` AS dom ON `rec`.`iddomicilioapertura` = `dom`.`iddomicilio`
    LEFT JOIN `tbl_entidad` AS ent ON `dom`.`identidad` = `ent`.`identidad`
```

Codigo yii:

```
public function traerRecibos() {
    $r = new CDbCriteria();
    $dx = TblDomicilio::model()->tableName();
    $ex = TblEntidad::model()->tableName();
    $r->select='t.idRecibo,DX.idDomicilio';
    $r->join = 'left join ' . $dx . ' DX on DX.idDomicilio = t.idDomicilio';
    $r->join = 'left join ' . $ex . ' EX on EX.idEntidad=DX.idEntidad';
    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $r,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize', Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
    )));
}
```

Relaciones de table tblRecibo:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'tblEstadoreciboHasTblRecibos' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblEstadoreciboHasTblRecibo', 'idRecibo'),
        'tblItemrecibowebs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblItemreciboweb', 'idRecibo'),
        'idCalendario0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblCalendario', 'idCalendario'),
        'idDomicilioApertura0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblDomicilio', 'idDomicilioApertura'),
        'idDomicilio0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblDomicilio', 'idDomicilio'),
        'idPaquete0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblPaquete', 'idPaquete'),
    );
}
```

I need to visualize the same SQL data but with `CDbCriteria`, I can not access the data from the `tblEntidad` table from `tblRecibo`.

Comment: SO is international website, please use only English in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine JOIN clause in this way:

```
    $r->join = 'left join ' . $dx . ' DX on DX.idDomicilio = t.idDomicilio ';
        . 'left join ' . $ex . ' EX on EX.idEntidad=DX.idEntidad';
```

In your code you just overwriting first assignment to `$r->join`.

You may also consider using [`with()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#with-detail), so you could reuse relations definitions to build JOIN conditions. See [this guide article about relations](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have the problem in the view, I do not understand how to pass that value from the third table. this is the code in the view of the columns that are related (tbl_Recibo and tbl_domicilio)